# Difference between BinaryFormatter and SoapFormatter for type handling

Tags: c#, serialization, binaryformatter, soapformatter

Here is a short code that works fine with BinaryFormatter and does not work properly with SoapFormatter:

```
       [Serializable]
       public class CustomDictionary : Dictionary<int, object>
       {
           public CustomDictionary() { } 
           protected CustomDictionary(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) : base(info, context) { }
       }

        var input = new CustomDictionary();
        input.Add(1, new Address("NYC", "Gold street", 17));
        input.Add(2, "mystring");
        input.Add(3, new Being("Serge"));

        IFormatter formatter = new SoapFormatter(); // works fine with BinaryFormatter() here
        FileStream s = new FileStream("test.data", FileMode.Create);
        formatter.Serialize(s, input);
        s.Close();
        FileStream s2 = new FileStream("test.data", FileMode.Open);
        var output = (CustomDictionary)formatter.Deserialize(s2);
        s2.Close();
```

Here, `Being` and `Address` are serializable classes. I basically want to be able to put any kind of objects as values in my custom dictionary.
If I use the SoapFormatter, after deserialization, values at index 1 and 3 are null in `output` (the recreated custom dictionary).
It seems to me that BinaryFormatter stores the type of the objects while the SoapFormatter does not.

Am I missing something?

Is there any way to have the same behaviour with the SoapFormatter than with the BinaryFormatter?

Thank you,

Comment: BinaryFormatter includes whole type information, which can make big trouble if you update assemblies. Soap is an Xmlformat, that also adds _some_ type information. Maybe you check the resulting Xml file and think for yourself if you could re-create the types from the given information or not. And then start a search on how to add these type information in Soap/Xml.

Comment: The question is moot - both `BinaryFormatter` and `SoapFormatter` are officially considered deprecated and actively dangerous, so "do not use" vs "do not use" :/

Comment: Does s and s2 match when you use SoapFormatter?  What are the differences?

Comment: @jdweng You mean the FileStreams ? Yes, they are identical in length (which is to be expected, I think). They both point to the same file.

Comment: Compare s and s2 to make sure they are exactly the same.  That will prove the serializer is the problem and not the writing and reading to the file.  If the steam is set to ASCII Encoding it could be changing the data and the problem may not be the serializer.